# point domains to folders under LAMP (Work of AddonDomains)

Tags: networking, server, apache2, dns, lamp

I have installed LAMP on Ubuntu without any problem and now if I point my domain to my VPS IP it works normally, I tried to use `.htaccess` but it didn't work for me

I want to point many domains to the same VPS IP but not displaying the same content: I mean that for example the first Domain points to a Sub Folder and the others to a different folder.

If I use CPANEL it's easy to click on `Addon Domains` but then I don't have any idea about what to do!

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! ;-) Next time, please use your [Shift] key for correct CaPiTaLiSaTiOn!  :-) (and using a spell-checker would be nice too...)

Answer (score 0):

There is a pretty good "how to" description for adding virtual hosts to your one Apache web server in the [Ubuntu serverguide](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/httpd.html#http-configuration). (see basic settings) There are also links to further references.